# Python Multiproceesing Threading Asyncio

Tags: python, multithreading, multiprocessing, python-multiprocessing, python-asyncio

im writing a program and i need to have more than two process processes running simultaneously and they share few data. While trying to do that i reserched on Threads, Multiprocessing, Asyncio. Threads will only run a single thread at a time due to GIL,Multiprocessing dont share data fast, asyncio has no use here  Now i'm quite jumbled up between these three.How to run simultaneously more than 2 proceeses?

Comment: What is the structure of the data you wish to process? That will affect how you do this.

Comment: @https://stackoverflow.com/users/750670/polarise some integers

Comment: You can refer to https://pymotw.com/2/multiprocessing/communication.html where they use a queue and a method called 'poison pill'. I strongly recommend this.

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet is probably the multiprocessing module.  --> [Process-based parallelism](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/multiprocessing.html)

Essentially, to create a multiprocess program the module just starts a new python process with whatever function you farm out to it on another core. In the past I have had CPU bound programs that benefited from parallel processing large amounts of data with similar functions, this is where I have found the most use cases. Other then case scenarios where I know I am CPU bound and run time matters, good program composition is usually a better and easier solution.